# Is it necessary to put Seaplanes on BB, CA etc without Air Superiority?

Tags: kantai-collection

It is always recommended to put Seaplanes on BB,CA etc for triggering [Artillery spotting](http://kancolle.wikia.com/wiki/Artillery_Spotting).

But, [according to wiki](http://kancolle.wikia.com/wiki/Artillery_Spotting#Introduction:), Artillery spotting can be triggered only after achieving [Air superiority](http://kancolle.wikia.com/wiki/Combat/Aerial_Combat#Fighter_Combat) (AS) or higher during aerial combat.

Maybe other equipment, like Radars or AA guns might be more useful without AS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: no, it is not necessary.

Long answer from [this reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/kancolle/comments/8nzl51/question_is_it_necessary_to_put_seaplanes_on_bb/?st=ji9xlo3c&sh=7474aca8):

Equipment setup is always situational
Sometimes you aren't able to artillary spot, so you can get creative with setups i.e. main gun + multiple secondaries/radars. 9/10 you will be able to art spot, so that's why bb/ca day da setups are so common/recommended.
AA guns have always been good wildcard equipment for aa obviously. Bonus fp from improved aa guns is also nice.
Radars can bump up los when necessary.